# reading user input in PL/SQL in Java

Tags: sql, jdbc, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running a database and trying to do all data handling through PS/SQL, and the thing is that once I establish the connection, I have this code, but it fails with the error of

> SQLException:Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED

The reason why I am executing it in java is because my assignment tells me that java will handle some things (that I haven't included here), but as for everything else (data manipulation and error checking), it must be handled by oracle. *Honestly this harsh restriction sounds silly to me.*

The intent of the code below is to read user input via an anonymous block and then print it to the DBMS output, though I'm not sure if that is even possible.
Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
try {
            CallableStatement cs = dbConnection.prepareCall("" +
                    "DECLARE" +
                    "myMessage varchar2 (20);" +
                    "BEGIN" +
                    "myMessage := '&myMessage';" +
                    "DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myMessage);" +
                    "END;");
            cs.execute();

        } catch (SQLException x) {
            System.out.println("SQLException:" + x.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: The "variable" replacement using `&` is a SQL*Plus feature and done **on the client**. The server can never accept input from a user who is sitting at a different computer. You *must* prompt the user for input through your Java program. PL/SQL ***never*** interacts with the end user.

Comment: That is the sort of confirmation I needed. I had my suspicions about it already. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just draw a picture which piece of code runs on which computer - then it will become evident.

Comment: For the record; I've seen the same error when erroneously pushing an empty SQL-string on Oracle.

Comment: IMHO @a_horse_with_no_name has provided the answer in his comment. It's just not possible by design.